# Unity In-App Purchase-How to check subscription is expired or not?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine, in-app-purchase

I want to implement subscription based in-app purchase through unity, but unable to find way how to track subscription is expired or not.

Any help would greatly appriciated
Thanks

Comment: check this link for ios: https://forum.unity.com/threads/solved-unityiap-subscription-purchase.454166/